# Eloquent WhereHas ALL related records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `Business` and `Services` model in my laravel application. A business can have many `Services` (via a businesses_services link table). I am trying to create a search function which will allow me to pass an array of services, I would like to search via eloquent all businesses that provide these services.

I have come up with this so far:

```
Business::all()
->whereHas('services', function($q) use ($treatments_wanted) {
    $q->where('service_id', $services_array);
})
```

The problem with this though is that it will show businesses that have at least one of the services attached, I want to list businesses that have ALL services listed in the `$services_array`.

Could someone explain the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to loop through all your services and adding `whereHas()`. Give this a try:

```
$query = Business::all();

foreach ($services_array as $service) {
    $query->whereHas('services', function($q) use ($service){
        $q->where('service_id', $service);
    });
}

$businesses = $query->get();
```